# How to realod specific blocks on Volt/Phalcon using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, frameworks, phalcon, volt

In my volt template:

```
    <div class="container">
        {% block conteudo %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
```

I want to load dynamically that block via ajax. All of my childs have block conteudo.
How i can do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you're mixing PHP with JavaScript.

So if you want to load something via AJAX just use empty DIV

`<div class="container"></div>`

then if you want to load something from server, ie part of view generated by Phalcon/Volt, create action that renders contents of that block.

In jQuery you can:

`$( "#result" ).load( "some/conteudo", { maybeSome: "params" });`

And you should have `SomeController` that have `conteudoAction` method that renders `some/conteudo.volt` view.

Your `some/conteudo.volt` should render only that part of view, ie:

`<h3>{{ post.title }}</h3><p>{{ post.someThing }}</p>`

Another way is to render you `div.container` contents by JavaScript with data obtained from serwer. To do that you could return JSON data from `SomeController::contuendoAction` and JavaScript part of your app will create HTML to your page.